# breaking out of the loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm having some trouble with breaking out of these loops:

```
done = False
while not done:
    while True:
        print("Hello driver. You are travelling at 100km/h. Please enter the current time:")
        starttime = input("")
        try:
            stime = int(starttime)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number!")
    x = len(starttime)
    while True:
        if x < 4:
            print("Your input time is smaller than 4-digits. Please enter a proper time.")
            break
        if x > 4:
            print("Your input time is greater than 4-digits. Please enter a proper time.")
            break
        else:
            break
```

It recognizes whether the number is < 4 or > 4 but even when the number inputted is 4-digits long it returns to the start of the program rather than continues to the next segment of code, which isn't here.

Comment: where do you change done to True?

Comment: try:
            stime = int(starttime) # do you mean starttime=int(starttime).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it "returns to the beginning of the program" is because you've nested while loops inside a while loop. The break statement is very simple: it ends the (for or while) loop the program is currently executing. This has no bearing on anything outside the scope of that specific loop. Calling break inside your nested loop will inevitably end up at the same point.

If what you want is to end all execution within any particular block of code, regardless of how deeply you're nested (and what you're encountering is a symptom of the issues with deeply-nested code), you should move that code into a separate function. At that point you can use return to end the entire method.

Here's an example:

```
def breakNestedWhile():
    while (True):
        while (True):
            print("This only prints once.")
            return
```

All of this is secondary to the fact that there's no real reason for you to be doing things the way you are above - it's almost never a good idea to nest while loops, you have two while loops with the same condition, which seems pointless, and you've got a boolean flag, done, which you never bother to use. If you'd actually set done to True in your nested whiles, the parent while loop won't execute after you break.

Comment: why do you have parens around True?

Comment: Ah, bad habit - sometimes C# syntax slips through.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want to use the variable `done` as a flag. So you have to set it just before your last break (when you are done).

```
...
else:
  done = 1
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` can take an optional *prompt* string.  I've tried to clean up the flow a bit here, I hope it's helpful as a reference.

```
x = 0
print("Hello driver. You are travelling at 100km/h.")
while x != 4:
    starttime = input("Please enter the current time: ")
    try:
        stime = int(starttime)   
        x = len(starttime)
        if x != 4:
            print("You input ({}) digits, 4-digits are required. Please enter a proper time.".format(x))                 
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number!")
```